# Error for .NETStandard1.6 PCL: "Your project is not referencing the ".NETPlatform,Version=v5.0" framework"

Tags: .net, .net-standard

To help reproduce the problem, the following steps are taken to create a .NETStandard1.6 PCL in Visual Studio 2015:

1. Create a new Class Library(Portable for iOS, Android and Windows).
2. In its Properties page, click "Target .NET Platform Standard".
3. Change .NETStandard form .NETStandard1.1 to .NETStandard1.6
4. Build this empty project.

The following error occurs:

```
>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\NuGet\Microsoft.NuGet.targets(140,5): error : Your project is not referencing the ".NETPlatform,Version=v5.0" framework. Add a reference to ".NETPlatform,Version=v5.0" in the "frameworks" section of your project.json, and then re-run NuGet restore.
```

The following is project.json:

```
{
  "supports": {},
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.NETCore.Portable.Compatibility": "1.0.1",
    "NETStandard.Library": "1.6.0"
  },
  "frameworks": {
    "netstandard1.6": {}
  }
}
```

Could anyone offer a tip on how to Add a reference to ".NETPlatform,Version=v5.0" in the "frameworks" section?  I tried the following:

"donet5.4": {}

"donet5.0": {}

Neither works.

Comment: Say goodbye to that. Switch to VS2017.

Comment: I'm looking forward to using VS2017, but not for another couple weeks. So much for helpful comments.

Answer (score 7):

For VS2015 at the very end of the .csproj file, add:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <NuGetTargetMoniker>.NETStandard,Version=v1.6</NuGetTargetMoniker>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error, I added the following in my `project.json`

```
"frameworks": {
            "netstandard1.4": {
                "imports": "portable-net45+win8+wpa81+wp8"
            }
            "netplatform50": {}
  }
```

This worked for me