# How to Reference ".NETPlatform,Version=v5.0" Framework in Xamarin.Forms Project?

Tags: xamarin.forms, visual-studio-mac

I'm currently working on a Xamarin.Forms project named ABCD, using macOS Sierra v10.12.6 and Visual Studio (VS) for Mac v7.3.2 (the steps leading up to this problem are detailed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48069346/how-to-set-autogeneratebindingredirects-in-visual-studio-for-mac)).

Having updated my **NETStandard.Library** package from version 1.6.0 to 2.0.1*, I notice that the **project.json** file still says:

```
"frameworks": {
"netstandard1.5": {}
}
```

**VS update this package to 2.0.1, despite **Terminal** showing that **dotnet --version** is 2.1.3.*

I went ahead and replaced `netstandard1.5` with `netstandard2.0` and rebuilt the project. But was then immediately met with this error:

> Error: Your project is not referencing the ".NETPlatform,Version=v5.0" framework. Add a reference to ".NETPlatform,Version=v5.0" in the "frameworks" section of your **project.json**, and then re-run NuGet restore. (ABCD)

I've tried to fix this in the following ways:

1 – Updating **project.json**:

```
"frameworks": {
    "netstandard2.0": {},
    ".NETPlatform,Version=v5.0": {}
}
```

2 ([source](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/10213#issuecomment-235049724)) – Updating **project.json**:

```
"frameworks": {
    "netstandard2.0": {},
    ".NETPlatform,Version=v5.0": {
        "imports": ["netstandard2.0"]
}
```

3 ([source](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/10213#issuecomment-235049724)) – Updating **project.json**:

```
"frameworks": {
    "netstandard2.0": {},
    ".NETPlatform,Version=v5.0": {
        "imports": [".NETCore,Version=v5.0"]
}
```

4 ([source](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/10213#issuecomment-235049724)) – Updating **project.json**:

```
"frameworks": {
    "netstandard2.0": {
        "imports": [".NETCore,Version=v5.0"]
}
```

5 ([source](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/10213#issuecomment-235049724)) – Updating **project.json**:

```
"frameworks": {
    ".NETPlatform,Version=v5.0": {
        "imports": ["netstandard2.0"]
}
```

6 ([source](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/12918), [source](http://code.fitness/post/2016/12/target-netstandard16.html)) – Updating **ABCD.csproj**:

```
<PropertyGroup> 
    <NuGetTargetMoniker> .NETStandard,Version=v2.0 </NuGetTargetMoniker> 
</PropertyGroup>
```

I thought I might find something helpful [here](https://xamarinhelp.com/dot-net-standard-pcl-xamarin-forms/) and [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/cesardelatorre/2016/06/28/running-net-core-apps-on-multiple-frameworks-and-what-the-target-framework-monikers-tfms-are-about/) but wasn't successful.

The same error from above still remains after having tried the above fixes. How do I fix this?

**EDIT:**

7 ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41684917/error-for-netstandard1-6-pcl-your-project-is-not-referencing-the-netplatfor/44422498#44422498)) – Updating **project.json**:

```
"frameworks": {
    "netstandard2.0": {},
    "netplatform50": {}
}
```

Still seeing the same error.

Comment: [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44422498/17034) suggests that the correct moniker is "netplatform50".  Sounds right.  Yuck what a mess, be sure to update your tooling.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but that didn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This [post](https://oren.codes/2017/04/23/using-xamarin-forms-with-net-standard-vs-2017-edition/) suggests not using project.json but instead to do a `dotnet migrate` in your project root folder to convert it so that it uses .csproj instead